# How to calculate only hours and minutes in between given dates and time?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a work schedule sheet in excel while working from home and somehow I am missing the formula.

Here's what I've done so far:
[image: image 1]

at Total per week it shows only 11:00 AM. 
Am I mistaking the formula somewhere?

```
= (C17-B17) +(E17-D17) +(G17-F17) + (I17-H17)
```

I want to get the hours and minutes.
Where I am mistaking?

NOTE: This is entirely on excel.

Comment: What's in the cells you are trying to sum up? DateValues, TimeValues? A result of 11:00AM looks like it might be correct but formatted wrongly.

Comment: @Variatus - There's no difference between date and time values in Excel.

Comment: @Enigmativity A time value is a number <0 whereas a date value must be a number >0.

Comment: @Variatus - No, it's not. Time is represented as a floating-point number between 0 and 1. 0 being midnight at the start of a day and 1 being midnight at the end. 0.5 is noon. When you add integer amounts you get days. Midday on the first of March this year is 43891.5, as an example.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are mistaken, good fellow. A TimeValue can't be zero and, arguably,it can't be 1. However, I stand corrected. I intended to say that a TimeValue is <1 and a DateValue >1. Perhaps the point is that we both know the facts and, therefore, both know that TimeValues are different from DateValues, in Excel.

Comment: @Variatus - A date value does not need to be greater than 1. It must be greater than or equal to 0. Any value, greater than or equal to 0, with a fractional component is a date value and a time value. That's why I saw they are the same thing. The whole part is the date and the fractional part is the time.

Comment: @Variatus - The docs on the `DateTime.FromOADate` in .NET say this: `The d parameter is a double-precision floating-point number that represents a date as the number of days before or after the base date, midnight, 30 December 1899. The sign and integral part of d encode the date as a positive or negative day displacement from 30 December 1899, and the absolute value of the fractional part of d encodes the time of day as a fraction of a day displacement from midnight. d must be a value between negative 657435.0 through positive 2958465.99999999.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your issue. It's quite simple. Once you obtain the total per week. Change the format -> Change your Total per week column's format to as required shown in image. 
[image: format]

Comment: If the total is more than 24 hours, then the format should be `[h]:mm`